# Does anyone know of a comprehensive exercise / stretching program that restores proper muscle balance and flexibility and releases tension?

Tags: strength-training, stretching, programs, muscle-imbalance, physical-therapy

The goal is health not so much strength, but being able to continue the program and build strength without sacrificing muscle balance would be a big plus.

I'm thinking there would be some way to quantify that all muscles are at the same relative strength level before continuing to strengthen them.

EDIT: Regarding relative strength, for example if you could leg press 300lbs but had never exercised your lower back and then went to do a squat, the imbalance could be disastrous. As another example, if your abs were very strong and erector muscles weak, then your body might use the abs for posture instead of the erectors.

Comment: Can you define "relative strength level", and explain what benefits you believe maintaining a consistent relative strength level across all muscles would bring?

Comment: @DavidScarlett I guess that's hard to quantify now that you mention it, but I'd some something that makes sense.  For example if you could leg press 300lbs but had never exercised your lower back and then went to do a squat, the imbalance could be disastrous.  As another example, if your abs were very strong and erector muscles weak, then your body might use the abs for posture instead of the erectors.  I know this isn't an elegant explanation, but hopefully communicates the gist.  Thanks

Comment: @g941 don't confuse "weak points" with "imbalances". If your lower back is a lot weaker than your quads, squatting will exercise your lower back until it catches up with your quads as long as you don't load too much on the bar. Conversely, a too-heavy squat attempt can be disastrous regardless of how balanced your strength is  
I understand your question but remember there's a thriving community of quacks selling "solutions" which "fix imbalances", having very little scientific evidence that they work any better than just lifting appropriate weights with proper form.

Comment: No generalized exercise program is going to correct all of your imbalances, whatever they claim - there's just no way that a single program could deal with the multitude of different imbalances that various people will have. The only way to do this would be to seek out a competent trainer and have them perform a thorough assessment.

Comment: You mention that you are not able to continue your program. Which program is this and specifically why are you not able to continue your program? If you want help you need to be more specific.

Comment: @Andy it's not so much that I can't continue it, but it's just that it's the closest I've found though doesn't exactly fit what I'm looking for unless you do the version where you pay for personalized sessions as opposed to self guided in which case it's pretty close. The program is Egoscue / Pain Free. I'd like a self guided program that's a book or video series or something like that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but this sounds above  my knowledge. I thought you referred to a strength training program. If it your lower back that is causing you pain I can recommend the McGill big 3 exercises and walking. That worked for me. Perhaps consult a physiotherapist. Swimming is also good for many sorts of pain.